# Angular 2 Routing Error with ModuleWithProviders

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-modules

[image]

I'm new in Angular 2 I need help on the routing part. I'm using http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

I got an error

> Exported variable 'routing' has or is using name 'ModuleWithProviders' from external module "/home/frank/angular/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module" but cannot be named.

Here is my code

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// used to create fake backend
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers/index';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing }        from './app.routing';

import { AlertComponent } from './_directives/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService } from './_services/index';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
 ],
declarations: [
AppComponent,
AlertComponent,
HomeComponent,
LoginComponent,
RegisterComponent
],
providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    AlertService,
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,

    // providers used to create fake backend
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

 export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas on the error? I also tried seimport { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';tting my "declaration": true, in tsconfig.js and also imported

Comment: Can you show the `app.routing` file. Looks like that's where the error is coming from

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this by doing:

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

And don't forgot to import ModuleWithProviders from @angular/core

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not need to import `ModuleWithProviders`. I think that you only needed to import that module in older Release Candiades (RCs). Currently, importing  `MgModule` will automatically allow providers which seems to be the only purpose for `ModuleWithProviders` [DOCS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ModuleWithProviders-interface.html)