# Angular 6: error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic - core and forms versions is same

Tags: angular6, package.json

My routing was not working correctly, I have separate paths for two components but still they were shown one below the other in second component's path, reason: below error in my console,
Inspite of trying the solution given here [ANGULAR 6: error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763710/angular-6-error-ts2315-type-modulewithproviders-is-not-generic),

I am still getting same error, and now it is not even compiling.
I am searching solution since past few hours but no luck.

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser.d.ts(45,9): error TS2315: Type >'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_module.d.ts(101,60): error TS2315: Type >'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.
>   node_modules/@angular/router/src/router_module.d.ts(105,38): error TS2315: Type >'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

Below is my package.json,

```
{
  "name": "cakewale",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "shallow-render": "^7.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

I was thinking to change the versions to 6.1.2, but I am scared it might result in altogether new errors, would anyone recommend that?
I am not able to figure out what am I missing, please help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use some new libraries and guess accidentally mismatched the versions of `@angular/core @angular/router @angular/platform-browser`

I removed the `^` sign from versions of all the three above to make sure their versions are exactly same, it worked.

Comment: please provide exact details.

Comment: @Daryl  I removed `^` sign from all the versions of core, router, platform-browser , so for ex. `^9.0.0`  was changed to `9.0.0` , this way it made sure which exact versions were needed. Hope this helps.