# Node modules fails on install in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm-install

I cannot install new npm package module within my Ionic project, i have these errors below after compilation:

For example when i run this command
"npm install @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli"
or this one
"npm install pouchdb"

[ng] i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

[ng] ERROR in node_modules/@angular/forms/src/form_providers.d.ts:22:9 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).

[ng] 22     }): ModuleWithProviders;
[ng]            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[ng] node_modules/@ionic/storage/index.d.ts:5:52 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).

[ng] 5     static forRoot(storageConfig?: StorageConfig): ModuleWithProviders;

Comment: Please share which commands you run and which command triggers this error.

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763710/angular-6-error-ts2315-type-modulewithproviders-is-not-generic/51774763

Comment: I installed ionic5 and and moved  "src" folder there